# Could not find Qt binding (looked for: 'pyqt', 'pyside') when rosrun

Tags: ros, pyqt, rosrun, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I install ros kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04, with python 2.7. `rqt_graph` shows properly, however, when I run `rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui` and `rosrun rqt_reconfigure rqt_reconfigure`. It shows the following message, my $PYTHONPATH is `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

`ros-kinetic-python-qt-binding` is already installed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/rqt_gui/rqt_gui", line 13, in <module>
    sys.exit(main.main())
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rqt_gui/main.py", line 59, in main
    return super(Main, self).main(argv, standalone=standalone, plugin_argument_provider=plugin_argument_provider, plugin_manager_settings_prefix=str(hash(os.environ['ROS_PACKAGE_PATH'])))
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qt_gui/main.py", line 336, in main
    from python_qt_binding import QT_BINDING
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from .binding_helper import loadUi, QT_BINDING, QT_BINDING_MODULES, QT_BINDING_VERSION  # @UnusedImport
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 252, in <module>
    getattr(sys, 'SELECT_QT_BINDING_ORDER', None),
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 98, in _select_qt_binding
    raise ImportError("Could not find Qt binding (looked for: %s):\n%s" % (', '.join(["'%s'" % b for b in binding_order]), '\n'.join(error_msgs)))
ImportError: Could not find Qt binding (looked for: 'pyqt', 'pyside'):
  ImportError for 'pyqt': No module named QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 89, in _select_qt_binding
    QT_BINDING_VERSION = binding_loader(required_modules, optional_modules)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 131, in _load_pyqt
    _named_import('PyQt5.%s' % module_name)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 111, in _named_import
    module = builtins.__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named QtCore

  ImportError for 'pyside': No module named QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 89, in _select_qt_binding
    QT_BINDING_VERSION = binding_loader(required_modules, optional_modules)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 163, in _load_pyside
    _named_import('PySide2.%s' % module_name)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_qt_binding/binding_helper.py", line 111, in _named_import
    module = builtins.__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named QtCore
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/257944/could-not-find-qt-binding-(looked-for:-%27pyqt%27,-%27pyside%27)-when-rosrun/) by [tngan](https://answers.ros.org/users/29837/tngan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2017-03-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-09-07**:
did you solve this problem? ı have the same problem too.

**Comment by [Anshul Paigwar](https://answers.ros.org/users/27126/anshul-paigwar/) on 2017-11-15**:
I am having a similar error, any solution???

**Comment by [siou12](https://answers.ros.org/users/33017/siou12/) on 2017-12-24**:
I had almost the same problem, turns out that it was the miniconda installer path that I had to comment out in my .bashrc in order to solve the problem.

```
# added by Miniconda2 installer
#export PATH="/home/kostas/miniconda2/bin:$PATH"
```

hope it works for you too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same issue, when I ran `rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph` , then it searches for `QtCore` in  the `pyqt` and `pyside`
modules. Actually I have already done: `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rqt` ,
`sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rqt-common-plugins` and
`sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-rqt-graph` . So every dependency was already installed.
The problem was that anaconda was messing up with my path (as mentioned in the comments).
So I commented the `export PATH="/home/usp/anaconda2/bin:$PATH"` in my `~/.bashrc` ,then close the terminal & reopen it. And everything was running smooth.

---

Originally posted by [warriorUSP](https://answers.ros.org/users/36100/warriorusp/) with karma: 30 on 2018-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0